# Using Qt 5.7.0 with gcc 4.4.7 on centos 6.7

Tags: qt, c++11, qmake

I would like to migrate from Qt 5.6 to Qt 5.7 on my workstation running centos 6.7. Everything's fine with Qt 5.6 but i am facing the following issue with Qt 5.7 after i have downloaded and installed it.

I am trying to run the elasticnode examples to check the installation but i have the following build error:

`cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"`

This error is related to the version of gcc which is 4.4.7 and does not recognize this option. The compiler flag used by Qt 5.7 to activate c++11 features is `-std=gnu++11` and with Qt 5.6 it was `-std=gnu++0x` and only this last flag is recognized by gcc.

In the .pro file of the elasticnodes example, nothing is set and so i assume that c+11 was disabled by default as described in the documentation     http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config but this is not consistent with the gcc command line that is finally generated by qmake.

So my question is , how to remove the new flag and set the old flag back in the .pro file , that is `-std=gnu++0x` instead of `-std=gnu++11` ?

I have tried to add the following lines :

CONFIG -= c++11

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x

but i get this error :

`/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:61: error: #error "Qt requires C++11 support"`

Does anyone knows how to properly set this flag ?

Comment: Is such an old compiler even supported by 5.7?

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html, gcc 4.9.1 is supported but i would prefer not to upgrade the compiler if possible

Comment: IIRC  you will need at least 4.8.x or something like that and that's if you built it from source. It is highly unlikely the prebuild version will work with such an old compiler. As the error says - you need a C++11 compiler.

Comment: As another option, you can try clang for building your project with Qt 5.7 instead of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.7 requires a C++11 compiler. The minimum supported GCC version is therefore GCC 4.6 (but higher versions are *highly* recommended). You can install a devtoolset (say, devtoolset-2, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos)) to get a better compiler.

Comment: Thanks and indeed, i think i have no other choice to use Qt 5.7 on centos 6.7 with GCC.